# compare two dictionary, one with list of float value per key, the other one a value per key (python)

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, bioinformatics

I have a query sequence that I blasted online using NCBIWWW.qblast. In my xml blast file result I obtained for a query sequence a list of hit (i.e: gi|). Each hit or gi| have multiple hsp. I made a dictionary my_dict1 where I placed gi| as key and I appended the bit score as value. So multiple values for each key.

```
my_dict1 = {

gi|1002819492|: [437.702, 384.47, 380.86, 380.86, 362.83],

gi|675820360| : [2617.97, 2614.37, 122.112],

gi|953764029| : [414.258, 318.66, 122.112, 86.158],

gi|675820410| : [450.653, 388.08, 386.27] }
```

Then I looked for max value in each key using:

```
for key, value in my_dict1.items():

    max_value = max(value)
```

And made a second dictionary my_dict2:

```
my_dict2 = {

gi|1002819492|: 437.702,   

gi|675820360| : 2617.97,

gi|953764029| : 414.258,

gi|675820410| : 450.653 }

I want to compare both dictionary. So I can extract the hsp with the highest score bits. I am also including other parameters like query coverage and identity percentage (Not shown here). The finality is to get the best gi| with the highest bit scores, coverage and identity percentage.

I tried many things to compare both dictionary like this :
```

First code :

```
matches[]

if my_dict1.keys() not in my_dict2.keys():

    matches[hit_id] = bit_score

else:

    matches = matches[hit_id], bit_score
```

Second code:

```
if hit_id not in matches.keys():

    matches[hit_id]= bit_score

else:

    matches = matches[hit_id], bit_score
```

Third code:

```
intersection = set(set(my_dict1.items()) & set(my_dict2.items()))
```

Howerver I always end up with 2 types of errors:

1 ) TypeError: list indices must be integers, not unicode

2 ) ... float not iterable...

Please I need some help and guidance. Thank you very much in advance for your time. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to do. What is `hit_id`? What is `bit_score`? It looks like your second `dict` is always going to have the same keys as your first if you're creating it by pulling the max value for each key of the first `dict`.

You say you're trying to compare them, but don't really state what you're actually trying to do. Find those with values under a certain max? Find those with the highest max?

Your first code doesn't work because I'm assuming you're trying to use a `dict` key value as an index to `matches`, which you define as a `list`. That's probably where your first error is coming from, though you haven't given the lines where the error is actually occurring.

See in-code comments below:

```
# First off, this needs to be a dict.
matches{}

# This will never happen if you've created these dicts as you stated.
if my_dict1.keys() not in my_dict2.keys():


    matches[hit_id] = bit_score  # Not clear what bit_score is?

else:
    # Also not sure what you're trying to do here. This will assign a tuple
    # to matches with whatever the value of matches[hit_id] is and bit_score.
    matches = matches[hit_id], bit_score
```

Regardless, we **really** need more information and the full code to figure out your actual goal and what's going wrong.

Comment: I end it up changing my whole strategy. I even had problem understanding what I want. Sorry really new to python and bioinformatic. Thank you anyway for ur help :) This question can be deleted I guess. Sorry for any trouble I caused